# login test with rspec + Capybara not redirecting to home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara, factory-bot

I'm trying requests tests with Capybara and it doesnt seem to work. This is my test file:

```
describe "Sessions", :type => :request do

  let(:company) { FactoryGirl.create(:company) }
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin, company_id: company.id ) }

  describe "login page" do
    it "signs me in" do
      visit '/users/sign_in'
      within("#new_user") do
        fill_in 'Email', :with => user.email
        fill_in 'Password', :with => user.password
      end
      click_button 'Sign in'
      expect(page).to have_content 'Agenda'
    end
  end
end
```

Throws the following Error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content 'Agenda'
   expected #has_content?("Agenda") to return true, got false
```

Im not sure if the problem is at logging in or at redirecting. But if i change the last line in the test for this:

```
expect(page).to have_content 'Invalid email'
```

I get the same Error.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

i'm using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for login

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing is to use `screenshot_and_save_page` to take a screenshot of the page just before the failing test, maybe you can determine what the problem is there.

Comment: thanks @smathy. Just like this: screenshot_and_save_page? Cause it's giving me undefined method error.

Comment: Sorry, you need [this plugin](https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot) to get that command, or check out [the Debugging section of the capybara readme](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#debugging) for how to get it using the `page` object.